# calculate number of repetition of character in string in c#

Tags: c#, string

how can I calculate the number of repetition of character in string in c# ?
example I have sasysays number of repetition of character 's' is 4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a version using LINQ (written using extension methods):

```
int s = str.Where(c => c == 's').Count();
```

This uses the fact that `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`, so we can filter all characters that are equal to the one you're looking for and then count the number of selected elements. In fact, you can write just this (because the `Count` method allows you to specify a predicate that should hold for all counted elements):

```
int s = str.Count(c => c == 's');
```

Comment: I tried in vs2008 and string does not seem to be IEnumerable.
Can you verify.
string.ToCharArray() is IEnumerable

Comment: @josephj1989, check again... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: In order for Intellisense to provide you with the LINQ extension methods, you might have to cast the string to `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is:

```
int numberOfS = str.Count('s'.Equals);
```

This is a little backwards - `'s'` is a char, and every char has an `Equals` method, which can be used as the argument for `Count`.
Of course, this is less flexible than `c => c == 's'` - you cannot trivially change it to a complex condition.

Comment: Definitely clever, although certainly less intuitive than writing out `c => c == 's'` (I'd say that code is more likely to cause pause).

Answer (score 3):

```
s.Where(c => c == 's').Count()
```

given s is a string and you are looking for 's'

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i < str.Length; i++) { 
    if(str[i] == myChar) {
        charCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution, to count number of occurrences of all characters :

```
var charFrequencies = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach(char c in s)
{
    int n;
    charFrequencies.TryGetValue(c, out n);
    n++;
    charFrequencies[c] = n;
}

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} instances of 's' in the string", charFrequencies['s']);
```

Comment: Nice one, it is very possible more than one letter is needed, and calculating it once is a good idea. You can also write `s.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());`, to achieve the same dictionary. I'm probably using too much LINQ `:P`

Answer (score 1):

```
        string s = "sasysays ";
        List<char> list = s.ToList<char>();
        numberOfChar = list.Count<char>(c => c=='s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
namespace Count_char
{
    class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++)
        {
            string s2 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(i));

            CountStringOccurrences(s1, s2);
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void CountStringOccurrences(string text, string pattern)
    {

        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
        {
            i += pattern.Length;
            count++;

        }
        if (count != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-->{1}", pattern, count);
        }

    }
}

}
```